# Casting an URL object to HttpURLConnection

Tags: java, android, url, casting, httpurlconnection

I am new in java and I am still dealing with the basic topics. I cannot really understand how the following lines work when obtaining a new HttpURLConnection by calling URL.openConnection() and casting the result to HttpURLConnection.

```
URL url = new URL("http://www.android.com/");
HttpURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
```

How can you instantiate the HttpURLConnection with the URL object if URL class does not inherit from HttpURLConnection?

According to the java API reference this is the hierarchy of both classes:

*Java.lang.Object ⇒ java.net.URLConnection ⇒ java.net.HttpURLConnection*

*java.lang.Object ⇒ java.net.URL*

As far as I know casting is used in the following way:

In this case HttpURLConnection is descended from URLConnection and Object.
Therefore, a HttpURLConnection is a URLConnection and is also an Object.

The reverse is not necessarily true: a URLConnection may be a HttpURLConnection, but it isn't necessarily. So you have to use casting.

But URL class and  HttpURLConnection ARE NOT related. Only trough OBJECT class.

That is what I cannot understand. Can someone help me?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: there is a method call `openConnection()` check what it returns in documentation ...

Answer (score 5):

You're not casting `URL`, you're casting the return value of `openConnection()` (`URLConnection`), which is deep down a `HttpURLConnection` when the address starts with `http://`.

Answer (score 0):

In the URL class is stated as follow for the `openConnection()`:

If for the URL's protocol (such as HTTP or JAR), there exists a public, specialized URLConnection subclass belonging
to one of the following packages or one of their subpackages:
java.lang, java.io, java.util, java.net, the connection
returned will be of that subclass. For example, for HTTP an
***HttpURLConnection*** will be returned, and for JAR a
JarURLConnection will be returned.